# ZFS and controller level mirroring

Tags: hard-drive, zfs, mirroring

If there are more than one SCSI controllers on your machine - there are disks from each controller - is there an option within ZFS to create a mirror of an existing pool so that sub mirror is picked from different controller than that of the initial one, instead of leaving this to admin or a cronjob to decide a best disk for the mirroring?

more details:

current OS booted pool:

consists of OSpool: c0t0d0 -- I have the following disks to choose a sub mirror

c1t0d0 , c2t0d0 , c0t0d1

wouldn't it be good if zpool had an option to choose the best disk for the mirror . this will help in breaking and readding the mirrors again in future for any maintenance so that consistency is not lost. vxvm does something like this

https://sort.symantec.com/public/documents/sf/5.0/aix/html/vxvm_admin/ag_ch_volumecreation_vm24.html

Comment: Could you show an example of what the pool you have at the moment looks like, and what you'd like the final result to be?

Comment: This is unclear. Can you describe in better detail?

Comment: Which OS? And why do you want ZFS to automatically decide what your vdev layout should be? Setting up pools and vdevs is basically a one-time event...

Comment: added more detail -- this is solaris10